# How can the builder patten use singleton in it's implement?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, builder

I ran across several references to the builder patter being implemented as a singleton:

From [Wikipedia: Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern): *"Abstract Factory, Builder, and Prototype can use Singleton in their implementations"*

How can the builder patten implement singleton? How do you maintain the state created by `buildParts()` when multiple threads are making calls to a builder that is a singleton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the Builders should be singleton.

If you really really wanted to I guess you could do something like this:

```
public final class Builder{
    private static final Builder instance = new Builder();

    private Part part1= null;

    private Part part2= null;
    ...

    public static Builder getInstance() { 
         return instance;
    }

    private Builder() { /*singleton  */ }

    public Builder buildPart1(Part p){
        part1 = p;
        return this;
    }
    ...build other parts similar;

    Product getResult(){
        return new ConcreteProduct(part1, part2 ...);
    }
}
```

But by re-using the same singleton instance, you would have to make sure you set all the values correctly and not accidentally re-use old values from previously built products.

Even with proper synchronization, I think the potential for bugs and surprises from other threads/ previous built production values leaking into your Product would not make it worth it.

Comment: I agree, I don't think it should be singleton. Additionally I cant think of a way to have it implement and still be tread safe.